How can I reset an array in a React state after a successful fetch request?
So, I'm collecting cellphone numbers from a textarea: the values are held in state.
I will validate them and/or add a country prefix based on whether or not they already have the prefix. For each validated number I want to store it in an array.
After I submit the data in the array in a fetch call, I want the contents of the array to be reset to an empty array to get it ready to receive a fresh batch of numbers.
I have decomposed the problem into two functions. One for processing the numbers and the other for making the fetch call
.
.
.
const [phoneNos, setPhoneNos] = useState('') // values from the textbox
const [validatedPhoneNos, setValidatedPhoneNos] = useState([]); // array to hold validated numbers

function addPhoneNosToDB () {
        fetch(`end_point`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                somefield: fieldValue,
                list: validatedPhoneNos
            }),
        }).then(r => {
            toast.success('Your list was added')
            setPhoneNos('');
            setValidatedPhoneNos([])    // ***
        }).catch(err => toast.warning(err)) 
    }

//function to validate and format numbers
function procPhoneNos () {
        if (phoneNos) {
            const countryCodePattern = /^(?:\+?234|0)?(7\d{8})$/;
            const phoneNumberPattern = /^(0|\+?234)(\d{10})$/;

            let list = phoneNos.split(',').map(phoneno => phoneno.trim());

            list.forEach(phoneNumber => {
                if (phoneNumber.match(countryCodePattern)) {
                    setValidatedPhoneNos(prev => [...prev, phoneNumber])
                } else if(phoneNumber.match(phoneNumberPattern)) {
                    setValidatedPhoneNos(prev => [...prev, phoneNumber.replace(phoneNumberPattern, '234$2')]);
                } else {
                    toast.warning("One or more phone numbers not properly formatted")
                    return
                }
            });
            
                        //call the function to submit formatted numbers to db
            addPhoneNosToDB()
        } else toast.warning("you need to enter at least one phone number")
    }

Testing this out, I get an empty array whenever addPhoneNosToDB was called. If I removed line *** I do get the numbers in the array but mostyly only after a second request. Also, all the previous phone numbers get retained in the array. How do I fix it so that the array elements only get cleared after a successful fetch request? Preferably without useEffect except if necessary.
Thanks

Where and how are you verifying/validating that the validatedPhoneNos state is not updated to an empty array? Are you just trying to console log validatedPhoneNos right after the enqueued update? Please [edit] to clarify in better detail what the issue is and provide any debugging details.

Does The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately help answer your question?

I'm calling the function addPhoneNosToDB which then uses the contents of the array in state for a fetch call

The validatedPhoneNos state is redundant. You're only using it to transfer the array of phone numbers between the functions. Since procPhoneNos calls  addPhoneNosToDB, just pass the list array from the one to the other.
Note: I've made other unrelated changes to your code. See comments.
const [phoneNos, setPhoneNos] = useState('') // values from the textbox

function addPhoneNosToDB(list) { // pass the list to the function
  fetch(`end_point`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      somefield: fieldValue,
      list // send the list
    }),
  }).then(r => {
    toast.success('Your list was added')
    setPhoneNos('');
  }).catch(err => toast.warning(err))
}

// function to validate and format numbers
function procPhoneNos() {
  if (!phoneNos) { // if not phone numbers show toast and 
    toast.warning("you need to enter at least one phone number");

    return;
  }

  const countryCodePattern = /^(?:\+?234|0)?(7\d{8})$/;
  const phoneNumberPattern = /^(0|\+?234)(\d{10})$/;

  let invalid = false; // a flag to check if there are invalid numbers

  const list = phoneNos.split(',')
    .map(phoneno => { // the map can be used to check and transform the numbers
      const phoneNumber = phoneno.trim();

      if (phoneNumber.match(countryCodePattern)) return phoneNumber;

      if (phoneNumber.match(phoneNumberPattern)) return phoneNumber.replace(phoneNumberPattern, '234$2');

      invalid = true; // set to true when invalid number is encountered

      return phoneNumber;
    });

  // show warning if the flag is true
  if (invalid) toast.warning("One or more phone numbers not properly formatted")

  //call the function to submit formatted numbers
  addPhoneNosToDB(list) // pass list to function
}

